# Splitting data frame in pandas by pairs of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
id          value    curr1 curr2
06263100612 136.91   EUR   RUB 
06337100254 822.23   EUR   BGN 
06341101120 2508.37  RUB   BGN 
06260101780 373.33   EUR   BGN  
07110100385 3829.60  USD   BGN 
06242101069 742.84   EUR   GBP 
06229100016 742.84   EUR   BGN
```

I want to split the dataframe into several dataframes, such that in each data frame I will have one pair of `curr1` and `curr2`.  For example: one data frame consists of the rows that have `curr1` == EUR and `curr2` == BGN, a second data frame consists of the rows that have `curr1` == RUB and `curr2` == BGN, etc.

How can I code this in pandas or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the columns into a set of unique tuples, then create a new dictionary where the keys are the tuples and the values are the subsets of the original dataframe:

```
dfs_by_curr_pair = {
    (curr1, curr2): df[(df.curr1 == curr1) & (df.curr2 == curr2)] 
    for curr1, curr2 in set(zip(df.curr1, df.curr2))
}
```

If you don't want a dictionary, you can make it a list instead:

```
dfs_by_curr_pair = [
    df[(df.curr1 == curr1) & (df.curr2 == curr2)] 
    for curr1, curr2 in set(zip(df.curr1, df.curr2))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and iterate over the result:

```
 for (curr1,curr2),df2 in df.groupby(["curr1","curr2"]):
      # df2 is a subset of df
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach this.

First create a column that combines the two currs

```
df['curr_comb'] = df['curr1'] + df['curr2']
```

You can then use this new column to isolate the different combinations. The following will select the xth unique currency combination:

```
df[df['curr_comb']==df['curr_comb'].unique()[x]]
```

Notice that

```
df['curr_comb'].unique()
```

will return an array of all the different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

First, we get unique couples

```
couples = set(list(zip(df['curr1'],df['curr2'])))
```

Then, we select

```
for couple in couples:
    print(df[(df['curr1']==couple[0]) & (df['curr2']==couple[1])])
    print('\n')
```

Here i print, but you can store them as you go in a list for example.

Output :

```
  curr1 curr2   identifier   value
0   EUR   RUB  06263100612  136.91


  curr1 curr2   identifier   value
1   EUR   BGN  06337100254  822.23
3   EUR   BGN  06260101780  373.33
6   EUR   BGN  06229100016  742.84


  curr1 curr2   identifier    value
2   RUB   BGN  06341101120  2508.37


  curr1 curr2   identifier   value
5   EUR   GBP  06242101069  742.84


  curr1 curr2   identifier   value
4   USD   BGN  07110100385  3829.6
```